# How do I double bend an object?

Tags: modeling

I need to model this object. How can I do it?

I imagine that I should use the bend modifier... It seems that two bending steps are required.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you start from scratch you can create a plane, stretch on X, tilt its edge with the *Shear* tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>):

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Extrude on Y, flatten the tip with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Bevel the vertices to round the tips if necessary:

[image]

Extrude faces along normals:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you start with a flat surface and can solidify it later, you can do with a simple geonodes setup:

[image]

[image]

It's similar to rotating $180°$ around $(-1, -1, 0)$ axis.